# ¿Como eliminar los archivos del directorio .Trash-0 en Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, root

estoy tratando de eliminar los archivos almacenados en Equipo/.Trash-0/files como usuario Root. He entrado con Nautilus he intento mandarlos  a la papelera pero no puedo.
He intentado con este comando:

```
sudo rm -fr ~/.local/share/Trash/files/*
```

Pero este elimina los directorios de la papelera normal. ¿Como podría vaciar este directorio?

Comment: Segun leo: `Trash-0 folder is created to improve file recovery for external drives. Whenever you mount an external disk, a . Trash-* directory will be created in the "root" directory where files are moved to if deleted from the GUI, like the trash on your desktop. Take a backup of the files and try to format the hard-disk.` Eso quiere decir que son los archivos enviados a la papelera desde un USB o algo montado externamente. Si ya no lo tienes montado eliminalos tal cual con el usuario root.

Comment: Hola masterguru, los archivos son del servidor web que tengo montado que los he ido eliminando mientras hacia pruebas, son directorios con imágenes . El propietario no es Root sino www-data. Pero no puedo borrarlos ni entrando con Nautilus

Comment: vaya, cosa rara... ¿has probado con `gksudo nautilus` para ejecutar el nautilus como root?  Pero no los elimines hacia la papelera, eliminalos mientras pulsas la tecla Shift + Supr, y asi se borran directamente sin pasar por alli  (ojo con eso, no me hago responsable si te cargas algo que no es, porque no hay vuelta atras cuando borras asi)

Comment: Hola masterguru pues si funciono como tú dices. Muchas gracias

Comment: Pues voy a redactar respuesta :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respuesta basada en los comentarios con el OP:

Tal como encontré buscando en google [*"linux .trash-0 folder"*](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+.trash-0+folder):

> Trash-0 folder is created to improve file recovery for external
> drives. Whenever you mount an external disk, a . Trash-* directory
> will be created in the "root" directory where files are moved to if
> deleted from the GUI, like the trash on your desktop. Take a backup of
> the files and try to format the hard-disk.

Eso quiere decir que son los archivos enviados a esa papelera desde un USB o algo montado externamente. Aun así el OP decia que fueron eliminados de forma manual, y que no podia eliminarlos ni con su usuario y el Nautilus, pues pertenecian a `www-data`.

La solución ha sido ejecutar el Nautilus como root, lánzandolo desde un terminal con

```
gksudo nautilus
```

y luego eliminando los archivos mediante su selección y pulsando la combinación de teclas `Shift + Supr` que **los elimina completamente sin pasar por la papelera** (ojo con esta combinación de teclas, pues no hay vuelta atras, se borran definitivamente).